# Can one disable TextDelimiter within Schema.ini for ado in mfc?

Tags: c++, csv, mfc, ado

I have to deal with importing CSV files. The legacy solution uses MFC and ADO text driver to manage this. I know that you can specify the `TextDelimiter`-option within the corresponding `Schema.ini` file.

The problem is, that it is impossible for some input files to specify a character that isn't used within that file!

All our files are CP1252 encoded - we cannot deal with other encodings, so a "☃" (SNOWMAN, U+2603) or stuff like that provide no solution.

If I omit a character, ADO seems to fall back to the default character (doublequotes):

```
[Import.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
TextDelimiter=  //← omit character doesn't work!
col1=...
```

I also cannot define a sequence of characters, which would reduce the risk of mismatches to an acceptable value:

```
[Import.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
TextDelimiter=@#+@ // produces error when opening the ADO connection!
```

So my question is: Is it possible to completly **disable** this *feature*? I just do not want any automatic text delimiting!

The code is implemented in C++ based upon MFC and ADO - so no ADO.NET solutions will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
TextDelimiter=none
```